# Prove by induction $\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot 2^{i-1} =(n-1)\cdot 2^n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

**PROBLEM**

Prove by induction $\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot 2^{i-1} =(n-1)\cdot 2^n+1$

**PROGRESS**

So far I've proven $P_1$ and written $P_k$, but im stuck at $P_{k+1}$. I have written $P_{k+1}$ as

$$(k+1)\cdot 2^k+(k-1)\cdot 2^k+1=2^{k+1}\cdot k+1$$

but I don know how to simplify it, or even how to go on from here.

Comment: Well you're done, you have just shown $P_{k+1}$...

Comment: @Suzet Essentially, I have to prove that $(k+1)*2^k+(k-1)*2^k=2^{k+1}*k$, but I dont know if it is the same, which is why I try to make the expressions identical.

Comment: Oh, okay, I thought you had in fact proven it (if I had to do it, I wouldn't add more details than this). All you have to do is to factorize by $2^k$ on the left hand side.

Comment: @Pablo The LHS combines into $((k+1) + (k-1)) \cdot 2^k$, and the RHS follows.

Comment: @TobyMakmakes sense, thank you

Comment: The $k + 1$ on the RHS should be in parentheses.  Also, you should show you obtained the expression on the LHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $S(k) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k i\cdot 2^{i-1},$ then

\begin{aligned}
S(k+1) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} i \cdot 2^{i-1} &= (k+1)\cdot 2^{k} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^k i\cdot 2^{i-1}\\ 
&=(k+1)\cdot 2^k + S(k)\\
&= (k+1)\cdot2^k+(k-1)\cdot 2^k + 1\\ 
&= \big((k+1)+(k-1)\big)\cdot2^k+1\\ 
&= (2k)\cdot2^k + 1\\ 
&= k\cdot 2^{k+1}+1\\
\end{aligned}
as desired. First, I split the sum into two parts: the final term and the rest. Then I identify that this rest is equal to $S(k)$ for which by assumption we know the value of. I insert the value of $S(k)$, then I factor out the $2^k$ multiplier, and then I do some final simplifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on looking for a induction method, I give another direct solution.

We want to evaluate $$S_n=1+2\cdot 2+3\cdot 2^2+\cdots+n \cdot 2^{n-1}.\tag1$$

But $$2\cdot S_n=2+2\cdot 2^2+3\cdot 2^3+\cdots+n \cdot 2^{n}.\tag2$$

Thus, by $(1)-(2)$, we have $$-S_n=1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^{n-1}-n \times 2^n=\frac{1(1-2^n)}{1-2}-n\cdot2^n=(1-n)2^n-1.\tag3$$

It follows that $$S_n=(n-1)2^n+1.$$